# Developed a Soft Keyboard - How to switch views/service?

Tags: android, image, service, keyboard, emoticons

I have currently developed a soft keyboard using the InputMethodService.

It currently creates a functional QWERTY Keyboard:

```
public class KeyboardIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private KeyboardView kbv;
private Keyboard keyboard;


@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,   
             KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            String codeText = (String) String.valueOf(primaryCode);
            char code = (char)primaryCode;

            if(Character.isLetter(code) )
            {
                if(caps)
                {
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
            }
            else if (Integer.valueOf(codeText)==3890)
            {
                System.out.println("Testing to see if I can make a switch here..");
                break;
            }
            else {
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
                break;
            }
      }





      @Override
     public View onCreateInputView() {


      kbv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
      keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
      kbv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
      kbv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

      return kbv;

}
```

I have a button on the keyboard and when it is pressed by the user, I would like it to change to a "different keyboard" - i.e. switch to a different view. I want this other keyboard to have emoticons on it. But have no clue how to make this switch.

Could anyone provide me some tips, solution or possibly some documentation that I could read over to understand this?

Answer (score 2):

You can inflate a layout on your onCreateInputView method.

> @Override
>       public View onCreateInputView() {
>
> ```
>     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
>     yourLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
>     return view;
>
>
> }
> ```

and then you can create more keyboards and set visibilities.

keyboardNums

> kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,
>   null);
>
> ```
>             keyboard = new Keyboard(mContext, R.layout.nums);
>             kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
>             kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(onKeyboardActionListener);
> ```

keyboard qwerty

> kv2 = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);

```
            keyboard2 = new Keyboard(mContext, R.layout.qwerty);
            kv2.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv2.setOnKeyboardActionListener(onKeyboardActionListener);
```